# What is the preimage of a braid in a covering space branched over the braid?

Tags: knot-theory, braid-groups, branched-covers

For a knot $K\subset \mathbb{S}^3$, one can construct the covering space branched over that knot by assigning elements of the symmetric group $S_n$ to each arc of the knot. You can find the knot group in the cover by using Fox's variation of the Reidemeister-Schreier algorithm.

Since you can always turn a knot into a braid, I'm interested in doing this over the braid, and seeing what kinds of braids you end up with. The inspiration is the example 10D10 from [Rolfsen](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/rolfsen.pdf), in which he demonstrates pictorially you can get a $(4,2)$ torus knot in a 3-fold branched covering space over the trefoil, a $(3,2)$ torus knot.

NEW IDEA: Trying to do something closer to what Rolfsen does: given the number of cycles in the representation $\pi(\mathbb{S}-K)\to S_n$, you know how many preimages of each component you have in the cover (for a branched cover, this will be less than $n$ for example). Now, for each twist in the braid in the base, there is a twist in the cover which exchanges components in the braid and corresponds to elements of the braid group. Say you do this over a trefoil, you three twists (a $3\pi$ rotation) in the torus knot.

So I think my problem reduces to finding the element of the braid group which corresponds to each exchange of the components in the base, which of course depends on the representation $S_n$.

FURTHER RESTRICTION: Clearly, if the branched cover itself is not simply-connected, you will have some trouble saying what *the* preimage of the knot is. If we need it, we could consider only those cases in which the cover is simply-connected, which can easily be checked.

PREVIOUS: If I had some kind of map

$\pi(\mathbb{S}^3-K)\to B_n$

whose image was the braid word represented by the knot $K$, I could do this in the cover. Since the knot group doesn't uniquely determine the knot, I guess such a map is pretty unlikely to be well-defined. But maybe you could have an algorithm for it if you just considered the relators at each knot crossing ($a=bcb^{-1}$, etc...) and considered the image of them under such a map.

Anyone know any generic results on the preimages of braids in branched covering spaces over braids?